# Confirming Heroku Preboot

Tags: heroku

**My Question:**

If I see these lines in `heroku logs`, does that imply that preboot is disabled?  If not, why not?

```
2015-02-04T14:48:00.674205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-02-04T14:48:00.720515+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from up to starting
```

My understanding is that preboot should fire up brand new dynos, get them ready to serve requests, start routing requests to them, then shut down the old dynos.  Nowhere in that process would I imagine dynos changing `from up to starting`.

**The Background:**

I'm working on a deploy script that automatically toggles preboot depending on whether any database changes will be made.  In testing the script, I'm watching the logs hoping to determine whether preboot is actually being used when it should.  I see preboot turning on in the console output of my script:

```
Enabling preboot for <snip>... done
```

Yet in the logs I am seeing what I pasted at the top.  I'm trying to reconcile these facts.

Answer (score 1):

One way to verify this is to watch the dyno ID number change. You can see the dyno ID by adding [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics) to your app.

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.2808254.d97d0ea7-cf3d-411b-b453-d2943a50b456 sample#load_avg_1m=2.46 sample#load_avg_5m=1.06 sample#load_avg_15m=0.99
```

You can watch for that "dyno" value to change once the new dynos are accepting requests.